# 'User removed' is counted twice in reputation tab when that user approved edits

Tags: bug, reputation, suggested-edits, profile-page

The [reputation tab of this <s>user</s> bot's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector?tab=reputation) is a bit off.

On June 15th, a user was deleted who (presumably) cast the final 'approve' vote on two suggested edits. On that day, SmokeDetector's reputation decreased from 299 to 295, but the reputation tab makes it look like a -8 change.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Arulkumar, I missed that somehow (and it wasn't suggested when posting this question). Seems to be a recently introduced bug, then.